# How to get user specific object using django generic class detailview?

Tags: django, generics, django-views

How do I get the current user related object using django's `generic class DetailView`? Using function based views, I can obtain the object like this:

```
def foo(request):  
  friendProfile = get_object_or_404(request.user.profile.friends,username="admin")
```

What is the equivalent using detail view? I'm guessing it's something related to `get_object` or `get_context_data` but I can't fully understand the documents.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request` is an attribute of class based views. To get the current user you should use `self.request.user`.

On a `DetailView` overload the `get_queryset` to edit the queryset used to get the object.

I don't know precisely how your friend model is defined but let's assume it has a foreign key pointing to your profile with a `related_name` set to `friend_of`. Your view could be:

```
class FriendProfileDetail(DetailView):
    model = Friend
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(friend_of=self.request.user.profile)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example for me?

Comment: Excellent! Thanks.